# This web page is supposed to have a lemon dropping and bouncing but I seam to have made mistakes and I can not find them

Tags: javascript, html

Here is the code.

I think the main problems are just things I can not see because I have been staring at it for too long. I've been looking at the logic of it and it all looks fine but I know I must have made some errors somewhere (I'm guessing the errors are mostly in the second script not the first.

```
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript1.2">

<!-- Begin
function BrowserCheck() {
var b = navigator.appName;
if (b == "Netscape") this.b = "NS";
else if (b == "Microsoft Internet Explorer") this.b = "IE";
else this.b = b;
this.v = parseInt(navigator.appVersion);
this.NS = (this.b == "NS" && this.v>=4);
this.NS4 = (this.b == "NS" && this.v == 4); 
this.NS5 = (this.b == "NS" && this.v == 5);
this.IE = (this.b == "IE" && this.v>=4);
this.IE4 = (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('MSIE 4')>0);
this.IE5 = (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('MSIE 5')>0);
if (this.IE5 || this.NS5) this.VER5 = true;
if (this.IE4 || this.NS4) this.VER4 = true;
this.OLD = (! this.VER5 && ! this.VER4) ? true : false;
this.min = (this.NS||this.IE);
}
is = new BrowserCheck();  
//  End -->
</script>
</HEAD>


<BODY>

<center>
Click on the screen to drop lemon<br>
<div id="staticBall" style="position:relative;visibility:visible">
<img src="lemon.png" height=30 width=30 alt="Static lemon">
</div>
</center>
<div id="ball" style="visibility:hidden; position:absolute; left:100;      top:10; height:34; width:34">
<img src="lemon.png" height=30 width=30 alt="Bouncing lemon">
</div>

<script language="Javascript1.2">
<!-- Begin
iter = 0;
setId = 0;
down = true;
up = false;
bouncingBall = (is.VER5) ? document.getElementId("ball").style
: (is.NS) ? document.layers["ball"]
: document.all["ball"].style;
stillBall = (is.VER5) ? document.getElementId("staticBall").style
: (is.NS) ? document.layers["staticBall"] :          document.all["staticBall"].style;
winH = (is.NS) ? window.innerHeight - 55 : document.body.offsetHeight - 55;
document.onmouseup = buttonUp;
if (is.NS4)
document.captureEvents(Event.MOUSEUP);
function buttonUp(e) {
if ( ((is.NS) ? e.which : event.button) != 1) return true;
if (setId != 0) clearInterval(setId);
bouncingBall.visibility="visible";
stillBall.visibility="hidden";
bouncingBall.left = (is.NS) ? e.pageX - 15 : event.offsetX - 15;
bouncingBall.top = (is.NS) ? e.pageY - 15 : event.offsetY - 15;
iter = 0;
setId = setInterval("generateGravity()", 20);
return true;
}
function generateGravity {
if ((parseInt(bouncingBall.top)+iter < winH) && down) {
bouncingBall.top = parseInt(bouncingBall.top) + iter;
iter++;
return;
}
else {
if ((parseInt(bouncingBall.top)< winH) && down) {
bouncingBall.top = winH + 5;
return;
}
down = false;
up = true;
if (iter < 0 && parseint(bouncingBall.top) > winH) {
clearInterval(setId);
bouncingBall.visibility = "hidden";
stillBall.visibility="visible";
setId = 0; 
}
if (parseInt(bouncingBall.top) > 0 && up && iter >= 0) {
bouncingBall.top = parseint(bouncingBall.top) - iter;
iter--;
if (iter%3 == 0) iter--;
return;
}
down = true;
up = false;
}
}
// End -->
</script>

<p><center>
</center><p>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are working with an old version of javascript that your browser probably isn't using.

There were two errors in the console when I copied it over to my machine.

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {

file:///home/tkrg/lemon.png Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
```

For the first error, it seems like () was not written for the function. It said

```
function generateGravity {
```

Should say

```
function generateGravity() {
```

For the second error, I think it is safe to assume that you have the picture of the lemon.

There were two other things that did not work:

```
parseint()
```

is now

```
parseInt()
```

and this:

```
getElementId()
```

is now

```
getElementById()
```

The full code

```
<SCRIPT>

function BrowserCheck() {
var b = navigator.appName;
if (b == "Netscape") this.b = "NS";
else if (b == "Microsoft Internet Explorer") this.b = "IE";
else this.b = b;
this.v = parseInt(navigator.appVersion);
this.NS = (this.b == "NS" && this.v>=4);
this.NS4 = (this.b == "NS" && this.v == 4); 
this.NS5 = (this.b == "NS" && this.v == 5);
this.IE = (this.b == "IE" && this.v>=4);
this.IE4 = (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('MSIE 4')>0);
this.IE5 = (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('MSIE 5')>0);
if (this.IE5 || this.NS5) this.VER5 = true;
if (this.IE4 || this.NS4) this.VER4 = true;
this.OLD = (! this.VER5 && ! this.VER4) ? true : false;
this.min = (this.NS||this.IE);
}
is = new BrowserCheck();  
</script>
</HEAD>


<BODY>

<center>
Click on the screen to drop lemon<br>
<div id="staticBall" style="position:relative;visibility:visible">
<img src="lemon.png" height=30 width=30 alt="Static lemon">
</div>
</center>
<div id="ball" style="visibility:hidden; position:absolute; left:100; top:10; height:34; width:34">
<img src="lemon.png" height=30 width=30 alt="Bouncing lemon">
</div>

<script>
iter = 0;
setId = 0;
down = true;
up = false;
bouncingBall = (is.VER5) ? document.getElementById("ball").style
: (is.NS) ? document.layers["ball"]
: document.all["ball"].style;
stillBall = (is.VER5) ? document.getElementById("staticBall").style
: (is.NS) ? document.layers["staticBall"] :          document.all["staticBall"].style;
winH = (is.NS) ? window.innerHeight - 55 : document.body.offsetHeight - 55;
document.onmouseup = buttonUp;
if (is.NS4)
document.captureEvents(Event.MOUSEUP);
function buttonUp(e) {
if ( ((is.NS) ? e.which : event.button) != 1) return true;
if (setId != 0) clearInterval(setId);
bouncingBall.visibility="visible";
stillBall.visibility="hidden";
bouncingBall.left = (is.NS) ? e.pageX - 15 : event.offsetX - 15;
bouncingBall.top = (is.NS) ? e.pageY - 15 : event.offsetY - 15;
iter = 0;
setId = setInterval("generateGravity()", 20);
return true;
}
function generateGravity() {
if ((parseInt(bouncingBall.top)+iter < winH) && down) {
bouncingBall.top = parseInt(bouncingBall.top) + iter;
iter++;
return;
}
else {
if ((parseInt(bouncingBall.top)< winH) && down) {
bouncingBall.top = winH + 5;
return;
}
down = false;
up = true;
if (iter < 0 && parseInt(bouncingBall.top) > winH) {
clearInterval(setId);
bouncingBall.visibility = "hidden";
stillBall.visibility="visible";
setId = 0; 
}
if (parseInt(bouncingBall.top) > 0 && up && iter >= 0) {
bouncingBall.top = parseInt(bouncingBall.top) - iter;
iter--;
if (iter%3 == 0) iter--;
return;
}
down = true;
up = false;
}
}
</script>

<p><center>
</center><p>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```